# Dbset naming rules and class naming rules

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I had a Dbset declared like so:

```
public DbSet<James_BobRelation> James_Bobs { get; set; }
```

my Sql table is called `James_Bobs`

the class holding the data was called `James_BobRelation`

This does not work... when making calls to this within a repository:

```
EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
context.James_Bobs;
// It thinks the table is called James_BobRelation instead?
```

and yet when I changes the class name to James_Bobs, it did work?

What's the rules?

---

Further more, this totally confused me... I have a database table called `Sausages`

the DbSet is like so:

```
public DbSet<Sausage> Sausages { get; set; }
```

When I called upon Sausages that actually worked! even though the class in this case was Sausage... **does Entity framework add the 's'** if it thinks it can? **it's SOO CONFUSING ME**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, it will be looking for James_BobRelations by default; you can change that behavior:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<James_BobRelation>().MapSingleType().ToTable("TableNameHere");
}
```

Basically the default behavior is to pluralize your object and infer the table name from that.  IE  it will infer a name of Sausages for a class named Sausage.

Comment: Are you seriousss... thankyou for confirming this, I have boiled my brain! Happy valentines day!

Comment: Where do I add this override?

Comment: put the override in your DbContext class, same place you specify your DbSet(s).

Comment: I think you meant DbModelBuilder - And also the MapSingleType is not required.